# Windows app single sign-on when server has Anonymous and Windows Authentication is enabled?

Tags: c#, winforms, single-sign-on, dotnet-httpclient, ntlm

Our customer has a Web API that is configured for both Anonymous and Windows Authentication.  They refuse to make any changes to this configuration.

Our C# WinForms application is trying to communicate with this API, but it must use Windows Authentication for the current logged in user.  The `WebClient` and `HttpClient` classes defaults to Anonymous Authentication and never attempts to send Windows credentials.

What do I need to do to allow the Desktop client to allow single sign-on with this API?

As a sandbox, I've built this WebAPI2 controller:

```
public class AuthenticateController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        var identity = User.Identity;
        var name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(identity.Name) ? "Anonymous" : identity.Name;
        return identity.IsAuthenticated
            ? $"{name} was authenticated using {identity.AuthenticationType} authentication."
            : $"{name} was not authenticated.";
    }
}
```

and in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
      <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Calling `http://localhost/api/authenticate` with a `WebClient` or `HttpClient` produces the result:

```
"Anonymous was not authenticated."
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` class supports [Windows authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication) by using:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

**Example**

If you create a new ASP.NET application with windows authentication having an API controller like following:

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

You can call it from a windows client like this:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:58045/api/values");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string[]>();
}
```

Comment: `[Authorize]` does the trick, but I don't have control over the server-side code or configuration.

Comment: The client code which I shared is sending the request using Windows Authentication. The only thing that client should do is what I shared in the answer. It's the server responsibility to check the authentication and authorization correctly.

Comment: If you are going to write a test code, you can rely on `[Authorize]` attribute, or if for any reason, you are not interested to use that attribute, you should use [the same logic](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) in your code to do the authentication.

Comment: Using what you have here, the client uses Anonymous Authentication first. 
 Only if Anonymous Authentication fails does it then try Windows Authentication.  Realise I don't have control over the server-side code or configuration, so I can't add `[Authorize]` to the server-side endpoint, nor can I disable Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: I mean, since you can not change the server side code, the question is about client side. Right? In the client side, the only way of using windows authentication is what I shared.

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't work because the server has Anonymous Auth enabled and that takes priority over Windows Auth. Are you saying there's no way to force the client to *demand* Windows Auth or bust?